# Show that $\exists $ a $3\times 3$ invertible matrix $M\neq I_3$ with entries in $\mathbb Z_2$ such that $M^7=I_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that $\exists $ a $3\times 3$ invertible matrix $M\neq I_3$ with entries in $\mathbb Z_2$ such that $M^7=I_3$.

**My try**:

Consider the space $X=GL_3(\mathbb Z_2)$ .Now $|GL_3(\mathbb Z_2)|=168$.By Sylow's Theorem $X$ has a Sylow-$7$ subgroup of order $7$ say $H$ .Since $H$ is cyclic so $H$ has an element  of order $7$.Hence $\exists  A$ such that $A^7=I_3$.

But how to find the matrix $A$? I can't proceed further.

I found that this question has been asked before.I don't want  a hit and trial method for solving this question.Is there a definite way?

Comment: $x^3+x+1$ is a primitive polynomial over the field of two elements, so its companion matrix will have order 7.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to say what it is. It suffices to show that one must exist. (In fact, in that Sylow $7$-subgroup, there are $6$ such matrices).